# C++ How to correctly print value of templated type from module

Tags: c++, templates, module, c++20

I have a vector class inside a module:

```cpp
// other_library.cpp
module;
#include <iostream>

export module mylibrary.other;

export template<class T> class Vector
{
private:
    T x, y;

public:
    Vector(T _x, T _y) : x(_x), y(_y) {}

    void Write()
    {
        std::cout << "Vector{" << x << ", " << y << "}\n";
    }
};
```

And inside main, I create a vector and print its contents:

```cpp
// main.cpp
import mylibrary.other;

int main()
{
    Vector<int> vec(1, 2);
    vec.Write();

    return 0;
}
```

However, I get the unexpected print to terminal:
`Vector{10x55a62f2f100c20x55a62f2f100f`

These are the build commands used:

```
g++-11 -std=c++20 -fmodules-ts -c other_library.cpp
g++-11 -std=c++20 -fmodules-ts -c main.cpp
g++-11 -std=c++20 -fmodules-ts *.o -o app
./app
```

Naturally, if I move the vector class to the main file the print works as expected. I know that module support is still somewhat experimental. But I would expect something simple like this to just work. But perhaps I'm doing something wrong?

### EDIT:

A kind-of broken hack is to manually include iostream at the top of the main file, before importing the module, like this:

```cpp
// main.cpp
#include <iostream>
import mylibrary.other;

int main()
{
    Vector<int> vec(1, 2);
    vec.Write();

    return 0;
}
```

This will correctly print the contents of the Vector. But why is this necessary? The point of putting stuff in module is to avoid the trouble of header-inclusion.

Thus, my question is now two-fold.

Comment: it seems that `", "` and `"}\n"` are treated as a `const void*`...

Comment: @Jarod42 If that was the case, this should work `std::cout << "Vector{" << x << "\n";`. Unfortunately, it doesn't. I'm also noticing that `std::endl` is not accessible inside the Write function. (which is perhaps more sad than funny)

Comment: As extra test, you might add a function in the module which calls `vec.Write()`. (I didn't try out module yet).

Comment: @Jarod42 same result.. but good idea!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems that there are still some challenges with modules. Example: I cannot use `std::endl` inside the `Vector.Write` member function.

A solution is to precompile the `iostream` standard header, which can be done like this:

```
g++-11 -std=c++20 -fmodules-ts -xc++-system-header iostream
```

The precompiled module will be stored in the gcm.cached/ directory, and will be an implicit search path for consecutive gcc-commands.

Now, I can completely avoid including the standard header, so the library file will look like this now:

```cpp
// other_library.cpp
export module mylibrary.other;
import <iostream>;

export template<class T> class Vector
{
private:
    T x, y;

public:
    Vector(T _x, T _y) : x(_x), y(_y) {}

    void Write()
    {
        std::cout << "Vector{" << x << ", " << y << "}"
                  << std::endl;
    }
};
```

And I don't need to do anything further in the main file - simply importing my library module is sufficient.

A big thank you to Šimon Tóth for writing about this in his [article on modules](https://itnext.io/c-20-modules-complete-guide-ae741ddbae3d).